# SQLite3 Offset not working after Case-When-Then-Else-End on Limit statement

Tags: database, sqlite

I have the below SQLite3 Query which is basically a cascading query running from a Python script, basically

- Try to get 50 results from Query A
- If Query A doesn't return 50 results then Fill it out with Query B
- If Query A & B don't return 50 results then fill it out with Query C

I also need to be able to offset the results of Query A/B/C. The problem is the OFFSET in "END OFFSET 50" causes a datatype mismatch error. I have removed the Offsets one by one and confirmed this is definitely the Offset which is causing issues.

Example of structure containing END Offset:

```
SELECT * FROM (subquery) 
ORDER BY column DESC 
LIMIT CASE WHEN 
(subquery to check for negative value) 
THEN 0 ELSE (subquery) END OFFSET offset    <- This Offset is the one that causes issues
```

Full query for reference:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT name, craft_profit, regular_sale_velocity, ave_cost, cost_to_craft
    FROM item
    WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 2 AND
    regular_sale_velocity NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
    regular_sale_velocity IS NOT NULL AND
    ave_cost NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
    ave_cost IS NOT NULL AND
    item_num IN 
    (
        SELECT item_result FROM recipe WHERE recipe_level_table <= 1000
    )
    ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT name, craft_profit, regular_sale_velocity, ave_cost, cost_to_craft
    FROM item
    WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 0 AND
    regular_sale_velocity < 2 AND
    regular_sale_velocity IS NOT NULL AND
    regular_sale_velocity NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
    ave_cost NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
    ave_cost IS NOT NULL AND
    item_num IN (
        SELECT item_result FROM recipe WHERE recipe_level_table <= 1000
    )
    ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT CASE WHEN 50-
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item
        WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 2 AND
        regular_sale_velocity NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        regular_sale_velocity IS NOT NULL AND
        ave_cost NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        ave_cost IS NOT NULL AND
        item_num IN (
        SELECT item_result FROM recipe WHERE recipe_level_table <= 1000
        )
        ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
    ) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 50-
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item
        WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 2 AND
        regular_sale_velocity NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        regular_sale_velocity IS NOT NULL AND
        ave_cost NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        ave_cost IS NOT NULL AND
        item_num IN (
            SELECT item_result FROM recipe WHERE recipe_level_table <= 1000
        )
        ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
    ) END OFFSET 50
)
UNION
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT name, craft_profit, regular_sale_velocity,
    ave_cost, cost_to_craft FROM item
    WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 0
    ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT CASE WHEN 50-
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item
        WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 0 AND
        regular_sale_velocity NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        regular_sale_velocity IS NOT NULL AND
        ave_cost NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        ave_cost IS NOT NULL AND
        item_num IN (
            SELECT item_result FROM recipe WHERE recipe_level_table <= 1000
        )
        ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
    ) < 0 THEN 0 ELSE 50-
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item
        WHERE regular_sale_velocity >= 0 AND
        regular_sale_velocity NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        regular_sale_velocity IS NOT NULL AND
        ave_cost NOT LIKE 'NULL' AND
        ave_cost IS NOT NULL AND
        item_num IN (
            SELECT item_result FROM recipe WHERE recipe_level_table <= 1000
        )
        ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50
    ) END OFFSET 50
)
ORDER BY ave_cost DESC LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier just  to union three queries with `LIMIT 50` and then add `LIMIT 50` to the result of the union?  You might end up pulling 100 rows you don't need, but it would be less complicated.

Comment: So the main reason for not limiting after getting all the results is because it's a combination of numbers and NULL. 

If I limit after then the Ordering displays the NULL results above the number based results which means I could lose real values which are much more preferred to NULL values in the results.

So for example if there are 125 results with only 25 real number results then the ORDER BY and LIMIT will cause only 50 NULL results to be displayed